# error (1054, "Unknown column 'usuariorol.id' in 'field list'") django 1.10

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

Buenas tardes, como ven presento el siguiente problema:
error (1054, "Unknown column 'usuariorol.id' in 'field list'") django 1.10

al momento de entrar al administrador selecciono la opcion usuariorol y me aparewe este error. el admin.py es asi:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
# Register your models here.

class RolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =('idrol','roltipo')

    class Meta:
        model = Rol


admin.site.register(Rol, RolAdmin)


class UsuariorolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("usuid", "rol_idrol", "usuario_id")

    class Meta:
        model = Usuariorol


admin.site.register(Usuariorol, UsuariorolAdmin)


class UsuarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["cc_usuario", "nombre_usuario", "apellido_usuario", "pass_usuario","telefono_usuario", "direccion_usuario", "correo_usuario", ]

    class Meta:
        model = Usuario

admin.site.register(Usuario, UsuarioAdmin)


class ComunicacionesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["idcomunicaciones", "nombreusuario_comunicaciones", "correo_comunicaciones", "telefono_comunicaciones", "mensaje_comunicaciones" ]

    class Meta:
        model = Comunicaciones

admin.site.register(Comunicaciones, ComunicacionesAdmin)


class ContratoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_usuario_contrato", "oferta", "fecha_expiracion",]

    class Meta:
        model = Contrato

admin.site.register(Contrato, ContratoAdmin)


class EventosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_eventos", "nombre_evento", "lugar_evento", "fechainicio_evento","fechafin_evento"]

    class Meta:
        model = Eventos

admin.site.register(Eventos, EventosAdmin)


class ObituariosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_obituarios", "nombre_obituarios", "lugarvelacion_obituarios", "lugarexequias_obituarios", "lugardescanso_obituarios", "fechavelacion_obituarios", "fechaexequias_obituarios", "horavelacion_obituarios", "horaexequias_obituarios","horadescanso_obituarios"]

    class Meta:
        model = Obituarios

admin.site.register(Obituarios, ObituariosAdmin)


class PlanesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_plan", "nombre_plan", "cobertura_plan"]

    class Meta:
        model = Planes

admin.site.register(Planes, PlanesAdmin)


class SolicitudAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["id_usuariosolicitud", "fecha_solicitud", "hora_solicitud"]

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitud

admin.site.register(Solicitud, SolicitudAdmin)


class TipoComunicacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["idtipocomunicacion", "nombre_tipo"]

    class Meta:
        model = Tipocomunicacion

admin.site.register(Tipocomunicacion, TipoComunicacionAdmin)


class UsuariosNuevosAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["idusuario_nuevo", "nombrecompleto_usuarionuevo", "telefono_usuarionuevo", "correo_usuarionuevo", "fecha_usuarionuevo", "hora_usuarionuevo"]

    class Meta:
        model = UsuariosNuevos

admin.site.register(UsuariosNuevos, UsuariosNuevosAdmin)
```

el models.py es asi:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class Comunicaciones(models.Model):
    idcomunicaciones = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombreusuario_comunicaciones = models.TextField()
    correo_comunicaciones = models.TextField()
    telefono_comunicaciones = models.IntegerField()
    mensaje_comunicaciones = models.TextField()
    tipo_comunicacion_idtipo_comunicacion = models.ForeignKey('Tipocomunicacion', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='TIPO_COMUNICACION_idTIPO_COMUNICACION', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'comunicaciones'


class Contrato(models.Model):
    id_usuario_contrato = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    oferta = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_expiracion = models.DateField()
    planes_id_plan = models.ForeignKey('Planes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='PLANES_id_Plan', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    usuario_cc_usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='USUARIO_cc_usuario', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contrato'


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.SmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


class Eventos(models.Model):
    id_eventos = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_evento = models.TextField()
    lugar_evento = models.TextField()
    fechainicio_evento = models.DateField()
    fechafin_evento = models.DateField()
    usuario_cc_usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='USUARIO_cc_usuario', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'eventos'


class Obituarios(models.Model):
    id_obituarios = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_obituarios = models.TextField()
    lugarvelacion_obituarios = models.TextField()
    lugarexequias_obituarios = models.TextField()
    lugardescanso_obituarios = models.TextField()
    fechavelacion_obituarios = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fechaexequias_obituarios = models.DateField()
    horavelacion_obituarios = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    horaexequias_obituarios = models.TimeField()
    horadescanso_obituarios = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    usuario_cc_usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='USUARIO_cc_usuario', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'obituarios'


class Planes(models.Model):
    id_plan = models.AutoField(db_column='id_Plan', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nombre_plan = models.TextField()
    cobertura_plan = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'planes'


class Rol(models.Model):
    idrol = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    roltipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rol'


class Solicitud(models.Model):
    id_usuariosolicitud = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fecha_solicitud = models.DateField()
    hora_solicitud = models.TimeField()
    usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='usuario', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'solicitud'


class Tipocomunicacion(models.Model):
    idtipocomunicacion = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_tipo = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tipocomunicacion'


class Usuario(models.Model):
    cc_usuario = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_usuario = models.TextField()
    apellido_usuario = models.TextField(db_column='apellido_Usuario')  # Field name made lowercase.
    pass_usuario = models.IntegerField()
    telefono_usuario = models.IntegerField()
    direccion_usuario = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    correo_usuario = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usuario'


class Usuariorol(models.Model):
    usuid = models.IntegerField()
    rol_idrol = models.ForeignKey(Rol)
    usuario_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usuariorol'


class UsuariosNuevos(models.Model):
    idusuario_nuevo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombrecompleto_usuarionuevo = models.TextField()
    telefono_usuarionuevo = models.TextField()
    correo_usuarionuevo = models.TextField()
    fecha_usuarionuevo = models.DateField()
    hora_usuarionuevo = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usuarios nuevos'
```

el error no me deja entra a la opcion de usariorol por favor ayudarme gracias.

```
OperationalError at /admin/jazmines/usuariorol/

(1054, "Unknown column 'usuariorol.id' in 'field list'")

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/jazmines/usuariorol/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

(1054, "Unknown column 'usuariorol.id' in 'field list'")

Exception Location:     /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query, line 277
Python Executable:  /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:    

['/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesexequiales',
 '/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Server time:    Mar, 19 Dic 2017 21:07:27 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute

                        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute

                    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute

                    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler

                raise errorvalue

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute

                    res = self._query(query)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _query

                rowcount = self._do_query(q)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _do_query

                db.query(q)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query

                    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    The above exception ((1054, "Unknown column 'usuariorol.id' in 'field list'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner

                    response = get_response(request)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

                        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

                        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in wrapper

                        return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view

                            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py in _wrapped_view_func

                response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in inner

                    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper

                    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapped_view

                            response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func

                        return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in changelist_view

                    selection_note=_('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__

                self._fetch_all()

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all

                    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__

                results = compiler.execute_sql()

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql

                    cursor.execute(sql, params)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute

                    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute

                        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__

                        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py in reraise

                    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute

                        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute

                    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute

                    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler

                raise errorvalue

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute

                    res = self._query(query)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _query

                rowcount = self._do_query(q)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _do_query

                db.query(q)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/jazmines/funeraria/jazminesenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query

                    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Cual es el método de las views que llamas cuando haces el login? si es "login(request)" está claro el problema, cuando valida el login, hace un render hacia el login.html por lo que siempre que loguees te va direccionar al mismo login.html...

Comment: rostan asi es, en ese caso como procedo?

Comment: Buenos lo que debes hacer es preparar un html main, el cual sea el primer pantallaso luego del login, algo así como un main.html, donde podrás cargar programas, noticias o información respecto al usuario logueado. te invito a que generes un html en blanco, lo cambies en la función login y pruebes, luego te dedicas a pulir ese html. Saludos!